# If external-ip of coturn is only used for aws?

Tags: stun, coturn

https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/c4477bfddd2cd51de1ad37032ca88330f3c44ed6/docker/coturn/turnserver.conf#L100

In turnserver.conf , I see a world " For Amazon EC2 users", if the external-ip is only used for aws?
I let the stun server run in the k8s cluster, and then expose it to the public network with the nodeport service, but the srflx returned by stun is a gateway address, not the external-ip which I set. My k8s cluster runs on Alibaba Cloud.
I hope someone can help me solve this problem, thank you！！！

Answer (score 1):

AWS EC2 instances, for the most part, run behind a NAT.  Even if you've assigned a public IP address (e.g. `1.2.3.4`) via the AWS Console, the instance only knows about the private network its on and is unaware of the public IP address assigned to it.  That is, the instance thinks its IP address is `172.31.5.6` because that's what the Operating System discovered at boot time. Port forwarding enables certain TCP and UDP ports to be forwarded from the public IP address to the private IP address that the EC2 instance is running on.

This typically isn't a problem for most services run on an AWS EC2 instance. With STUN running in full "2 IP address and 2 port mode", the server needs to advertise its alternate IP address back to the client, should the client want to conduct NAT behavior and filtering tests.  But it would be incorrect for the STUN server to send back `172.31.5.7` as its alternate IP - the client has no way of reaching that IP since its private.

Similarly for TURN, when port allocations occur, the server needs to send back the public IP address of the EC2 isntance to the client who allocated it.  It would be bad if the client requested a TURN port to share with another peer - only for the TURN srever to send back `172.31.5.6`.

Hence, for a STUN or TURN server to be hosted behind a NAT, a set of command line parameters or configuration parameters are needed to tell the server what its "real" IP addresses are.  The STUN/TURN software will use these IP addresses for sending responses back to clients.